# Unable to set or remove a login PIN on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, login, pin

After my computer decided to run some updates, I was unable to login with my PIN. I had to do a password reset. I'm trying to re-enable the PIN, but I'm having difficulties.

I'm in Settings > Accounts ? Sign-in options. Under the PIN section, I should see an option to change or reset my PIN. However, that option doesn't appear. Instead, there's a button labeled Add. See this screenshot:

[image: Add PIN button]

When clicking the Add button, I get the following dialog:[image: We need to verify your identity for myemail@somedomain.com.]

No matter what I enter in the box, it disappears once I enter the same number of characters as the length of the PIN I had been using, regardless of which characters I enter. When the dialog closes, nothing further happens.

How can I set a PIN?

Comment: Looks like a problem with your Microsoft account. You might need to sign out, convert to a local account and sign back in.

Comment: Typically you need to remove the pin then enable it.

Comment: @Ramhound: Except, as I stated above, there doesn't appear to be a way to remove the PIN. If there's something way other than using the settings app, please enlighten me.

Comment: Screenshot would be helpful.  Be sure you sanitize it.

Comment: I've added screenshots. See my edit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After receiving no replies here, I asked this question over on [Microsoft's support site](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security/unable-to-log-in-with-a-pin/2d87217e-d38d-45ef-afec-5d39c8b9c90f?tm=1513954803097&rtAction=1514569641874). I'm copying the reply I got there, with the one modification I had to make to get it to work.

> *Step #1: Delete the Ngc folder.*
>
> 1. Use your password to log in to Windows 10.
> 2. Open File Explorer and paste this in the URL box: `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Microsoft`.
> 3. Right click `Ngc` folder and choose Properties.
> 4. Navigate to Security tab and click on Advanced button.
> 5. Locate the Owner section at the top and click Change link.
> 6. Enter the object name to select enter Administrators, if you’re using administrator account, or your user name and click Check Names and click OK.
> 7. Check Replace owner on subcontainers and objects and click Apply and OK. Now you should be able to access the `Ngc` folder.
> 8. Open the `Ngc` folder and perform steps 3-7 on each subfolder.
> 9. Open `Ngc` folder, select all files and folders in it and delete them.
>
> *Step #2: Start creating a new PIN.*
>
> After you’ve deleted everything from Ngc folder, you can create new PIN for your Windows 10 device by doing these steps:
>
> 1. Go to Settings app, then Account Settings.
> 2. Choose Sign-in Options and click Add a PIN.
> 3. Follow the instruction to add a new PIN.
> 4. Test your PIN using the Command Prompt (Admin).
> 5. If you cannot find the Command Prompt Admin, you can enable it using Command Prompt and typing `net user administrator /active:yes`
> 6. After enabling built-in administrator account, you may logon and try resetting the password of the account which is not working. You may disable it later once you are done by entering `net user administrator /active:no` in Command Prompt. You can use this also if you want to change passwords or PINs in other User Accounts.

---

*Note: I don't know whether it's permissible to copy this answer as I did, even with my one addition. If it isn't, feel free to edit this answer and just link to the solution.*

Comment: It worked for me but I think I can provide a tip. You probably wouldn't be able to delete Ngc with your permission. (Even though you ARE the admin. Duh.) Download Unlocker, which is a program that allows you to remove with the highest permission. Use this program to remove Ngc folder.

Comment: To be able to delete the folder, a local windows admin account is required. If you only have an online MS account, you need to create this one first.

Comment: Thank you, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Power Shell version of Scott's answer that worked for me.

After running this as admin, I was unable to create a PIN until after restarting the computer first.

```
$passportFolder = 'C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Ngc'

if (Test-Path $passportFolder)
{
    takeown /f $passportFolder /r /d y
    icacls $passportFolder /reset /t /c /l /q
    
    Remove-Item $passportFolder -recurse -force
}
```