# How to remove WebAuthN credentials from onboard-TPM on Win10 device?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, tpm, windows-hello, credentials-manager

Latest builds of Windows 10 allow browsers (at least Edge and Chrome) to use on-board TPM device for [WebAuthN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebAuthn) passwordless authentication.

It does work for me and on test sandbox sites - I can generate private-public key pairs, store private key in TPM and send public key to server for futher authentication.

The issue is that I cannot find a way to clear the saved keys.
I haven't tried erasing the whole TPM yet since I don't want to mess with BitLocker.

The question is how can I clear WebAuthN credentials (keys) stored in platform TPM running on Windows 10.

Is it even possible?

[image]

Comment: Try: (1) In Microsoft Edge > click the ellipsis > select Settings > Passwords & autofill > Manage passwords button > hover over password > click the X button. (2) Control panel > User Accounts > Manage your credentials > Web Credentials > down arrow > Remove. Windows Credentials might also be worth a look.

Comment: @harrymc both options didn't work for me

Comment: Windows Hello is not necessarily backed by a TPM.

Comment: @bedrin  Am I correct in assuming that you cleared these credentials by clearing TPM?  My device doesn’t have a TPM and I’m not sure where else to look into.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Microsoft command line tool `certutil` can be used to view and delete these WebAuthN keys.

**Disclaimer: it's very easy to delete the wrong key, so make sure that you are happy to accept the risk that you might delete the wrong key; there is no undo.**

To view your WebAuthN keys, from a command prompt, run:

`certutil -csp NGC -key`

WebAuthN keys have names that look like `<sid>/<guid>/FIDO_AUTHENTICATOR//<rpIdHash>_<user id>`

You need to identify the key that you want to delete, and then to delete a WebAuthN key, from an administrator command prompt, run:

`certutil -csp NGC -delkey <name>`

Comment: By the way, you can view the keys in the TPM with the `certutil` command too, from an administrator command prompt, run: `certutil -csp TPM -user -sid 23 -key` and then after running the `-delkey` mentioned in the post, you will notice that there is 1 fewer key in the TPM, confirming its removal.

Comment: When I do `-delkey` it responds that I need administrative privileges. When I run it as admin it does not find the user keys.
Is there a way to achieve it as a normal user?

Comment: @papaya your command doesn't yield results, most likely because of `-sid 23`, that's probably e.g a specific user ID on your machine

Comment: I made a small app that makes this easier: https://github.com/passwordless/webauthn-fido2-key-remover

Comment: @BenjaminH, pass `-sid 22` when you run the command as admin. 22 is "Local System".

Answer (score 4):

Windows don't have a UI for this which is very irritating when you work with Webauthn.

So I built a small tool that helps with this, it's on github: https://github.com/passwordless/webauthn-fido2-key-remover.

It's using certutil under the hoods but makes it a bit safer and easier to operate.

Answer (score 2):

I recorded the authentication process with [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and discovered several operations on several files in `%SystemRoot%\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Ngc` that looked suspicious.  A bit of googling suggests that is [indeed where Windows Hello credentials are stored](https://www.passcape.com/windows_password_recovery_windows_hello_credentials).

There are answers (e.g., [this one on this site](https://superuser.com/questions/1279400)) that suggest you can simply delete this directory’s content to remove all your Windows Hello credentials.

I tried renaming this folder (as SYSTEM by using [PsExec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)), and while it did remove my WebAuthn credentials, it also left me unable to create a new PIN in the “Sign-in options” UI.  I’m not sure if rebooting will help.

---

Edit: After several reboots I got a prompt saying there was something wrong with my Microsoft account.  (I use a local account, but am signed into a Microsoft account.)  After I signed in again, NGC was restored to the initial state and working properly again.

Answer (score 1):

TPM, like most certificate repositories, does not seem to support the delete operation.

I base this observation on the Microsoft article
[TrustedPlatformModule](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/trustedplatformmodule/?view=win10-ps),
describing itself as:

> This reference provides cmdlet descriptions and syntax for **all TPM cmdlets**.

The list does not include any PowerShell cmdlet for deleting certificates.

You could try to create a revocation certificate and import it into the TPM,
which might nullify the existing certificate.
If it works, this will not delete it, just add a revocation record
(that is if TPM works like any other certificate repository).

The only option I could find to delete anything is by clearing totally the TPM.
As you are using BitLocker, see the post
[Will clearing the TPM make BitLocker encrypted data unavailable?](https://superuser.com/questions/1149802/will-clearing-the-tpm-make-bitlocker-encrypted-data-unavailable)

Quoting from the post:

> If you clear the TPM, the encrypted drive will only be accessible
>   using the recovery key.
>
> So in your case it should be ok to clear the TPM chip. Afterwards,
>   reboot and enter the recovery key. Once inside Windows, you can
>   re-enable the TPM chip and set a new PIN.

I would suggest, just in case, to backup the BitLocked disk
(and perhaps even disabling BitLocker) before such operations.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick and dirty Node.js script to help anyone using windows quickly and easily remove **ALL FIDO CERTS**.

Its extremely rough, and could use error-handling / logging. Modify to suit your own needs.

PROCEED WITH CAUTION!:

```javascript
const util = require('node:util');
const exec = util.promisify(require('node:child_process').exec);

async function NUKE_ALL_CERTS() {
  const { stdout, stderr } = await exec('certutil -csp NGC -key');
  let output = stdout.split("\r\n")
  .filter((element) => {
    return /FIDO_AUTHENTICATOR/.test(element);
  })
  .map((element) => {
    return `certutil -csp NGC -delkey ${element}`;
  });

  await Promise.all(output.map((element) => {return exec(element)}));

  console.log(output);

}
NUKE_ALL_CERTS();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).