# Where does Windows 10 save Passkeys?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, passwords, webauthn

I went to https://webauthn.io/ with Chrome & Firefox to test the Passkey & WebAuthn functionality and created multiple credentials there. Everything worked nicely.

I was then looking for the stored credentials in Chrome until I realised they are stored in Windows.

[image: Credentials]

You can see, there are multiple credentials to choose from, and they are only offered for this particular website.

So my questions are: **Where does Windows store these? Where can I see what other saved credentials exist? Where can I delete them?**

I tried in Windows Credential Manager but there is nothing that resembles to what I'm looking for.

Comment: Those are not Passkeys (yet), by the way. They are stored with Windows Hello.

Comment: Those are stored credentials handled by the Credential Manager, and those are not Passkeys, and webauthn.io option, of course is a stored WebAuthn credential.

Answer (score 0):

Windows stores them in the Trusted Platform Module (TPM). Currently Windows does not offer a GUI to view all of your WebAuthn credentials (they're not really passkeys) stored on your machine. For an alternative way, see here: [How to remove WebAuthN credentials from onboard-TPM on Win10 device?](https://superuser.com/questions/1527685/how-to-remove-webauthn-credentials-from-onboard-tpm-on-win10-device)

However, you can open Google Password Manager via Chrome to view all the credentials that you have stored. Here, you can also delete them (https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/13168025?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=).

It's expected that Windows will release a "Passkey / WebAuthn manager" with one of the next Windows 11 releases (Windows 11 Insider Preview Build 23486 already shows it: https://www.howtogeek.com/901125/windows-11-will-have-its-own-passkey-manager/).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).